# How can one say "Close!" in the context of a game or sport

Tags: spoken-language

When playing a game like tennis or badminton, it often happens that after a long rally, my opponent hits the ball so that it *just* goes out.  In English, I would sometimes say something like "Close!" (not always; it gets annoying if you say it too much).  What would the German equivalent be?

On a similar note, I will from time to time say "Gute Schlag!" or "Schöne Schlag!" if my opponent hits a good shot -- if that sounds ridiculous, it would be good to hear about that too ;)

Thanks!

Comment: I play Badminton. You often say "knapp aus" (out) or "noch so gerade drin" (in) or "noch auf der Linie" (in). For out you also often say "nur ein bißchen" or "nur ein Stück aus" when your opponent asks how much, or you say "so viel" while showing with your fingers how much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent to "Close!" in german is "Knapp!". It's "Guter Schlag!" and "Schöner Schlag!" but other than that those phrases are perfectly common and noone will think it sounds ridiculous.

Comment: "**Fast!**" is also a common expression to use for "*Close!*" in German. It is the short form of "**Fast drin!**".